# How to override isclick() sigal in Pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a class BooleanButton contains extra boolean flag to toggle every click. After each click, I want it to emit a signal and the slot will receive the boolean flag. I just write the following, but of course, it won't work.

```
class BooleanButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, name):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, name)
        self.bool = False

    def clicked(self, bool):
        self.bool = not self.bool
        self.emit(self.bool)
```

After creating the object, it connects to a slot. When I click this button, a swapping true-false signal will send to the slot.

```
bool_btn.isclicked[bool].connect(widget.func)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is that PyQt 4 or 5?

Comment: It is PyQt 4. Thanks.

Comment: Did you know `QPushButton` has this behavior built-in? Just call `button.setCheckable(True)`

Answer (score 1):

First, don't call a method `clicked`, that will hide the buttons `clicked` signal.

If you want to define a new signal, you need to do so using `QtCore.pyqtSignal`, then you can connect the `clicked` singal to a slot that will in turn emit your custom signal. Example:

```
class BooleanButton(QPushButton):

    isclicked = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self, name):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, name)
        self.bool = False
        self.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    def on_clicked(self, bool):
        self.bool = not self.bool
        self.isclicked.emit(self.bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

As three_pineapples said, `QPushButton` comes with this feature built-in. Here's a simple example illustrating this behaviour.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Click me", self)
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

    def onClicked(self, checked):
        if checked:
            self.lineEdit.setText("Button checked")
        else:
            self.lineEdit.setText("Button unchecked")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So your `BooleanButton` is actually just a `QPushButton`.